# Selenium only working in non-headless mode?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, headless

i want to use Selenium on this page: https://www.avis.com/en/home

Without the headless-mode everything works fine with that code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, sys, time
import xlwings as xw
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from random import choice
from selenium import webdriver     
from sys import platform 

WAIT = 1
link = f"https://www.avis.com/en/home"
cd = '/chromedriver.exe'
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option ('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])            
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36")    
driver = webdriver.Chrome (path + cd, options=options)
driver.get (link)
print(f"Read location VIE...")
driver.find_element_by_id("PicLoc_value").send_keys("VIE") 
driver.find_element_by_id("PicLoc_value").click()
time.sleep(WAIT)
print(f"Read from date 2021-07-06...")
driver.find_element_by_id("from").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("from").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("from").send_keys("07/06/2021") 
time.sleep(WAIT)
print(f"Read to date 2021-07-21...")
driver.find_element_by_id("to").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("to").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("to").send_keys("07/21/2021") 
time.sleep(WAIT)
driver.find_element_by_id("res-home-select-car").click()
```

But when i uncomment the line
`options.add_argument('--headless')`
it is not working anymore

I allways get this error message:

```
Read location VIE...
Read from date 2021-07-06...
Read to date 2021-07-21...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\Upwork\JeffG\scrapeAvis.py", line 59, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("res-home-select-car").click()
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button name="button" id="res-home-select-car" ng-class="{'margin-top-90':false &amp;&amp; vm.expandState &amp;&amp; isAuthenticated}" class="btn btn-red selectMyCar hideMeFix btn-primary-avis" ng-if="!vm.isOneClick" ng-mousedown="vm.selectCarClicked = true" ng-click="vm.getVehicles.submit(resForm)">...</button> is not clickable at point (391, 417). Other element would receive the click: <div class="flyoutWrapper background_img suppress-lazyloading" imgsrc="/content/dam/avis/na/us/common/offers/avis-redbackground-600x250.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.web.768.504.webp" request="background" style="background-image: url(&quot;/content/dam/avis/na/us/common/offers/avis-redbackground-600x250.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.web.768.504.webp&quot;); opacity: 1;">...</div>
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.124)
```

Why is here selenium working only wihtout the headless mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using headless mode you should set the screen size since default screen size in headless mode is 800x600.
That's why in headless mode you have the `ElementClickInterceptedException` error for the code that is running fine in the regular mode.
So, try adding

```
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
```

Also, we usually add this:

```
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
```